# Do I still need source :gemcutter in Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, gemcutter

I have a file "Gemfile" in my Rails project root.

It says `source :gemcutter` in the very first line.

Do I still need the line? If I'm correct, `http://rubygems.org/` is the official source, and Gem Cutter was merged into `rubygems.org`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're correct.  You don't need it any longer, and yes, it was merged.

Make sure you have an alternate source specified:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Here's what I get:

Your Gemfile doesn't have any sources. You can add one with a line like 'source :gemcutter'

Comment: this answer is wrong.  I just got a stack trace that went away as soon as I added `source :gemcutter`.  Of course `source :rubygems` should work as well.

Comment: I'll expand the answer, I was making the assumption he already had the source rubygems line.

Answer (score 8):

You still need it. Instead of using :gemcutter, use :rubygems instead.